# Magento 2 How to create Custom Field on Customer Address form and save it's value

Tags: magento2, custom-field, customer-address-attribute

I want to create custom field on Customer address form as per below screenshot currently I create field but did not save it's value.

I have create field using three point:

1. Create Customer_address type attribute.
2. Create Block File Vendor\Extension\Block\Address\Field\Addressplace
3. Bind Template File on this Block file

So, the Field is displayed but does not save its value as per the below screenshot.

https://i.imgur.com/YQaraz9.png

How Can I fix it this Issue ?

Comment: Share your code full and otherwise, it is not possible to debug.

Comment: For your requirements, you need to follow this : https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/add-address-field/